# django accessing one-to-one key calls __setattr__ unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, one-to-one

I have a django model including two model classes (UserProfile and UserNotification). Each profile has optionally a last_notification. Here are the class fields defined in models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    last_notif = models.OneToOneField('UserNotification', null=True, blank=True, default=None,
                                      on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

class UserNotification(models.Model):
    shown = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(UserNotification, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        print("SET ATTR", key, value)
```

I have this [context-processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) function:

```
def process_notifications(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(...)
        notif = profile.last_notif
```

When the last line in process_notifications is called, my overwritten **setattr** method in UserNotification is called for all fields in UserNotification class. That is not supposed to happen? Am I right? Any idea why that happens?

I am sure that **setattr** is called there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called because the act of accessing `profile.last_notif` loads the UserNotification object from the database, since it hasn't previously been loaded. Doing this obviously requires that all of the fields of the instance are set with the relevant values from the db.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I checked that in debug mode and you are correct. It regenerates the objects and sets the attributes via __setattr__().